# How are parameters get mapped in reduce function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

The MDN defines reduce() as below:

The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

Let's not take anything for granted and just analyse the syntax of below statements:

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const reducer = (y, x) => y + x;

// 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
// expected output: 10

// 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
```

1. reducer is a function that takes two parameters and return their sum
2. reducer is executed on each element of the array, but 'each element of the array' is only ONE parameter, why can i assume that the SUM is the other parameter and cached somewhere waiting for the next add operation? and why can i assume reduce is returning the sum at the end?

Could someone answer these questions? From someone coming from other language background e.g. C which also has function concept. I am often confused by Javascript's syntax.

and that's how i get more confused when i see:

```
const pipeline = [
  array => { array.pop(); return array; },
  array => array.reverse()
];

pipeline.reduce((xs, f) => f(xs), [1, 2, 3]);
```

because again, according to MDN, The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

only this time,

reducer: (xs, f) => f(xs)

accumulator: [1, 2, 3]

array1: pipeline

then how do we explain its behaviour similar to our first example in English?

Comment: You stopped reading too soon. "Your reducer function's returned value is assigned to the accumulator, whose value is remembered across each iteration throughout the array and ultimately becomes the final, single resulting value."

Comment: **1**. the reducer accepts four arguments, the first two are compulsory (see the lack of square brackets). You can pass more than that, as in any JS function, but they will be ignored. **2**. `Array.prototype.reduce` is not about sum, you can do several other things, like counting, calculating averages, flattening etc. Reduce is about using an *accumulator* while iterating each element in the array.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks, Raymond. My bad habit. Stopped reading too soon :(

Comment: Why is Jack's answer deleted?! I was trying to ask follow-up questions

Comment: @RaymondChen in the 2nd example, pipeline is the array to reduce, (xs, f) => f(xs) is the reducer function, and [1, 2, 3] is the accumulator init value, how do we justify and explain that in English?

Comment: From the page, that "you've read": [How reduce() works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#How_reduce()_works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> reducer is executed on each element of the array, but 'each element of the array' is only ONE parameter, why can i assume that the SUM is the other parameter and cached somewhere waiting for the next add operation?

The callback provided is called multiple times, once for each item in the array (or, for `length - 1` times, in case no initial value is provided). You could easily implement this yourself:

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const reducer = (y, x) => y + x;

Array.prototype.myReduce = function(callback, initialValue) {
  let accum = initialValue === undefined
    ? this.shift()
    : initialValue;
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    accum = callback(accum, this[i], i, this);
  }
  return accum;
}
// 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.myReduce(reducer));
// expected output: 10

// 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.myReduce(reducer, 5));
```

Just because you pass *one* function to `.reduce` (or to any other function) doesn't put a limit on how many times that function can be called.

> and why can i assume reduce is returning the sum at the end?

That's just how the method is defined - like with the implementation above, the accumulator (or `accum`) gets reassigned for every iteration, and passed to the next invocation of the callback.

The browser's native implementation of the method isn't actually written in Javascript like above, but its functionality is the same (for the most part).

The `pipeline` works the same way. For every element of the array provided, the accumulator is reassigned, and the next element is called with the new accumulator. Here, there's an array of functions which are being called, and each function's return value is being used as the next accumulator, and the value returned by the last function call is what the whole `.reduce` call resolves to.

```
const pipeline = [
  array => { array.pop(); return array; },
  array => array.reverse()
];

pipeline.reduce((xs, f) => f(xs), [1, 2, 3]);
```

Item 1: initial value (accumulator) is [1, 2, 3]. Plugging into `array => { array.pop(); return array; }` and you `.pop()` its last value (the 3, resulting in `[1, 2]`, then you return the array.

Item 2: Accumulator (return value of last iteration) is `[1, 2]`. Plug it into `array => array.reverse()`, and you get the same array, reversed: `[2, 1]`.

There are no more items in the array, so this `[2, 1]` is the value that the whole `reduce` call evaluates to.

Comment: in the 2nd example, pipeline is the array to reduce, (xs, f) => f(xs) is the reducer function, and [1, 2, 3] is the accumulator init value, how do we justify and explain that in English?

Comment: It works the same way - it iterates through the array, performing an operation relative to each item, and returning a value to be used as the next accumulator. For the `pipeline`, the array happens to be an array of functions, and the result of each call is passed along as the next accumulator, until the end, and that final call's result is what the whole `.reduce` resolves to

Comment: in 1st example, reducer is (y, x) => y + x; it works on each of array element [1, 2, 3, 4], this makes sense. but in 2nd example, reducer is (xs, f) => f(xs), what the heck is it? and how it works on each of array element of pipeline?

Comment: `(y, x) => y + x` adds the accumulator to the current item being iterated over, and returns the sum. Similarly, `(xs, f) => f(xs)` calls the current item being iterated over with the accumulator, and returns the result. The `.reduce` callback (here, the `f(xs)` function invocation) is run for every item in the array, as explained at the beginning of the answer.